# parse xml with php using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following XML result simplexml_load_string()...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[Email] => xxxx@xxx.com 
[Acount] => 123123123 [Pin] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
[StartDate] => 20131204 
[EndDate] => 20131204 [XML] => 1 [State] => 1 [Pays] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
[Collections] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [Collection] => Array ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Trx_id] => 6200106301 ) [Trx_Date] => 2013-12-04 07:44:04 [Trx_Payment] => 243.00 [Trx_MontoNeto] => 229.45 [Trx_Number] => 42183710 [Trx_PaymentMean] => Pago ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Trx_id] => 6200081097 ) [Trx_Date] => 2013-12-04 07:43:58 [Trx_Payment] => 160.00 [Trx_MontoNeto] => 150.47 [Trx_Number] => 42183698 [Trx_PaymentMean] => Pago ) 
        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Trx_id] => 6200173497 ) [Trx_Date] => 2013-12-04 07:43:25 [Trx_Payment] => 78.00 [Trx_MontoNeto] => 72.42 [Trx_Number] => 42183631 [Trx_PaymentMean] => Pago ) 
) 
[Tickets] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Receptions] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Retreats] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Retreat] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Trx_Date] => 2013-12-04 14:04:36 [Trx_Payment] => 0,000.17 [Trx_MontoNeto] => 0,000.80 [Trx_Number] => 56757 [Trx_RetreatMethod] => bla bla bla [Trx_TypeCodIdentif] => C.U.I.L. [Trx_NumberCodIdentif] => 234234234 [Trx_Bank] => bank. [Trx_Address] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [City] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Province] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) ) [Credits] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Debits] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

I'm trying to recorver in a foreach clause all element like Trx_Id, Trx_date, etc...

can anyone post code to do that?

I've tried using

```
foreach ($xml->object as $dato) {
    print_r('data ' . $dato->field[2]);
}
```

but nothing ...!

***UPDATE:!!!!***

using the following approach

```
foreach($xml->Collections->Collection as $result){ 
    print_r('id ' . $result['Trx_id']. '<br>');
    print_r('date ' . $result['Trx_Date']. '<br>');
    print_r('Trx_Payment ' . $result['Trx_Payment']. '<br>');
    print_r('Trx_Number ' . $result['Trx_Number']. '<br>');
    print_r('Trx_PaymentMean ' . $result['Trx_PaymentMean']. '<br>');
    print_r('......<br>');

}
```

I can olny get Trx_id

as you can see

```
id 6200106301
date 
Trx_Payment 
Trx_Number 
Trx_PaymentMean
```

please take in care the structure

```
[Collections] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [Collection] => Array ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Trx_id] => 6200106301 ) 
            [Trx_Date] => 2013-12-04 07:44:04 [Trx_Payment] => 243.00 
            [Trx_MontoNeto] => 229.45 
            [Trx_Number] => 42183710 
            [Trx_PaymentMean] => Pago )
```

using vardump !!...

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public 'Email' => string 'xxxx@xxxx.com' (length=24)
  public 'Acount' => string 'xxxxx' (length=7)
  public 'Pin' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
  public 'StartDate' => string '20131204' (length=8)
  public 'EndDate' => string '20131204' (length=8)
  public 'XML' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'State' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'Pays' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
  public 'Collections' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
      public 'Collection' => 
        array (size=13)
          0 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]
              ...
          2 =>
```

UPDATE 2:

Here is Pure XML called directly using web Browser

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree       
is shown below.
<Report>
<Email>xxxxx@dddddd.com</Email>
<Acount>234234234</Acount>
<Pin/>
<StartDate>20131204</StartDate>
<EndDate>20131204</EndDate>
<XML>1</XML>
<State>1</State>
<Pays/>
<Collections>
<Collection Trx_id="123123132">
<Trx_Date>2013-12-04 07:44:04</Trx_Date>
<Trx_Payment>444.00</Trx_Payment>
<Trx_MontoNeto>444.45</Trx_MontoNeto>
<Trx_Number>333333</Trx_Number>
<Trx_PaymentMean>blabla</Trx_PaymentMean>
</Collection>
<Collection Trx_id="34534345">
<Trx_Date>2013-12-04 07:43:58</Trx_Date>
<Trx_Payment>160.00</Trx_Payment>
<Trx_MontoNeto>150.47</Trx_MontoNeto>
<Trx_Number>666666</Trx_Number>
<Trx_PaymentMean>blabla2</Trx_PaymentMean>
</Collection>
```

Comment: `$dato->Email` instead of `$dato->field[2]`

Comment: $dato->Collections->Collection[0]->Trx_id , that will get you started, var_dump it as you go.

Comment: I just update the post... sin using one comment I can make one step but I cannot get working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

```
$collections = $xml->xpath("//Collection");
foreach($collection as $collection) {
    $id = $collection['Trx_id'];
    $date = $collection->Trx_Date . '';
    $payment = $collection->Trx_PaymentMean . '';
    ...
}
```

Comment: yep... but it seems to be that Trx_Id its an array of one position only? I cannot figure out how it's structured and How can I access data easily.

Comment: @Ppp give your XML as well

Comment: Samy please check up update 2 where I post pure xml!

Comment: Ok, with this structure, you will only access `Trx_id` as an attribute, since the others are children... I updated my code, please check.